# Selenium: ElementNotVisibleException while trying to click the element with text as My Account onhttps://www.phptravels.net/

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

When I tested [phptravel](https://www.phptravels.net/) website and tried to click on the **myaccount** link with the below code.
Selenium returns **ElementNotVisibleException** during the execution. What is the thing that I missed?

**Source code**

```
public void login(WebDriver driver) {
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.phptravels.net/");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div[1]/a")));
    // Error on here 
    myAccount.click();
    WebDriverWait myAccountWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    myAccountWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"li_myaccount\"]/ul")));
    loginLink.click();
    WebDriverWait loginWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    //loginWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\\\"loginfrm\\\"]/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[1]/input")));
    username.sendKeys("user@phptravels.com");
    password.sendKeys("demouser");
    loginBtn.click();
}
```

Comment: Can you increase wait time n check

Comment: 10 seconds is consider long enough. Selenium execution is very fast one.

Comment: where is myAccount initialized?

Comment: could you share your console with exception information

Comment: This post is brought up in meta [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371538/how-to-deal-with-an-abusive-user-answerer-plus-abuser-to-other-answers) cc @Rajagopalan

Answer (score -5, accepted):

To `click()` on the element with text as **My Account** instead of `visibilityOfElementLocated()` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* through **`elementToBeClickable()`** method and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.phptravels.net");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//nav[@class='navbar navbar-default']//li[@id='li_myaccount']/a[normalize-space()='My Account']"))).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: php_travels_login_click]

Comment: Two Questions: 1. How you get the xpath? Why is it different from me? 2. Why chaining the click method to wait until is work but click on the element is not working?

Comment: @peterwkc Answers: 1. You don't get readymade optimized _xpath_ anywhere, you have to write one as per the prevailing _HTML DOM_. 2. Technically, this is not method chaining, `ExpectedConditions` **elementToBeClickable()** returns the _WebElement_ and we have optimized our code to invoke `click()` directly without any additional line. let me know if you have further queries.

Answer (score 0):

**Modify the code as below:**

On your WebDriverWait keep the xpath as below with *By* type:

```
By myAccountBy = By.xpath("//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right']/ul/li[1]/a");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(myAccountBy));
```

**OR**

Hardcode the xpath like below.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.Xpath("//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right']/ul/li[1]/a")));
```

Then keep the same xpath for **myAccount** WebElement as below

```
@FindBy(xpath="//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right']/ul/li[1]/a")
public WebElement myAccount;
```

In short, to click the MyAccount you have to keep this xpath

**//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right']/ul/li[1]/a**

Answer (score 0):

myAccount webElement is not initialized in your code.

In case you want to click on My account link you can use this :

```
WebElement myAccount = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='collapse']/descendant::ul[3]/li[@id='li_myaccount']/a")));
myAccount.click();
```

Note that you can't use **link Text** as that is **text nodes** .

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create `WebElement` then use `elementToBeClickable` Expected Condition for the same this way you can resolve the issue

```
WebElement myAccount = driver.findElement("Your locator");
```

Now use `wait`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(myAccount));
myAccount.click();
```

Also maximize the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a best practice to add the explicit wait after loading the URL. I am able to click the Account link based on the below modified XPath.

**Xpath:** `//nav//li[@id='li_myaccount']//a`

**Working Code:**

```
    driver.get("https://www.phptravels.net/");

    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
    //wait is added in order to complete the page loading
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("PHPTRAVELS"));

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//nav//li[@id='li_myaccount']//a")).click();
```